# Seeking Help to Implement Autoplay Background Music in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm currently facing a challenge with my WordPress website. I want to add a feature where background music starts playing automatically when a visitor loads the page. However, due to browser policies and restrictions, the music doesn't play unless there's some form of user interaction. This issue is causing errors in the console, and the autoplay functionality isn't working as intended.

I have tried several approaches, including using prebuilt plugins and even attempting to create a custom plugin, but none of these solutions have resolved the issue. I am looking for any guidance or suggestions on how I can successfully implement this functionality. The goal is to have the background music autoplay without any user interaction right from the page load.

Any insights or advice on this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is simply not possible due to browser restrictions.